# MediaElementJS tocando o cache ao invés da música atual

Tags: javascript, jquery, streaming

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var stream = 'http://somdomato.com:8000/stream.mp3';
    var nocache = '';

    $('#tocando').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#player').mediaelementplayer({
      //   pluginPath: 'https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mediaelement/',
      //   shimScriptAccess: 'always',
      startVolume: 0.4,
      alwaysShowControls: true,
      features: ['playpause','volume'],
      audioWidth: 145,
      iPadUseNativeControls: true,
      iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
      //AndroidUseNativeControls: true,
      success: function(player, node) {
        player.addEventListener('pause', function () {
        player.setSrc('');
      }, false);
      player.addEventListener('stalled', function () {
        var checkNetworkStateTimer = setInterval(function () {
          if (!paused) {
            if (node.networkState == 1 || node.networkState == 3) {
                                 var nocache = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
                                 player.setSrc(stream+'?nocache='+nocache);
                                 player.load();
                                 player.play();
                                 console.log('re-connecting after stalling due to networkState: '+node.networkState); //2 indicates NETWORK_LOADING state
                             }
                         }
                     }, 3000);

                 }, false);
         player.addEventListener('error', function () {
             var checkNetworkStateTimer = setInterval(function () {
                 if (!paused) {
                     if (node.networkState == 1 || node.networkState == 3) {
                         var nocache = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
                         player.setSrc(stream+'?nocache='+nocache);
                         player.load();
                         player.play();
                         console.log('re-connecting after error due to networkState: '+node.networkState); //2 indicates NETWORK_LOADING state
                     }
                 }
             }, 3000);
           }, false);




             },
             error: function () {
                 console.log('error log');
             }


    });


  });
```

Só que na maioria das vezes ao pressionar o pause e depois o play o player toca uma versão em cache ao invés da música atual no Streaming(Shoutcast + sc_trans).

Tentei seguir isso: https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/issues/1321#issuecomment-84600421

Mas não deu certo, o player algumas vezes toca e outras ele retorna pro pause, ou toca e não dá pause...

Código completo: http://ix.io/zYM

Comment: Estranho, o problema parece não está no código e sim na url: http://somdomato.com:8000/stream.mp3 , mesmo acessando ela, a música continua como se fosse em um cache, você não tem outra url para testar?

Comment: Mas a questão, nem o cache em sí, é que o botão de play/pause não funciona corretamente, http://somdomato.com:8000 esse é o link da stream. Eu tenho uma versão em produção e outra aqui no meu PC a do meu PC que está com esse problema...

Comment: Outra coisa muito importante que eu tentei e não consegui, é nesse mesmo código acima, caso a stream caia e volte o player começa a tocar novamente sozinho...